# Is it possible to alter behavior of any object's method in advance?

Tags: javascript

I need to achieve the following: if one accesses method `foo()` of object `obj` (performs `obj.foo()`), then what happens instead is `obj.bar("foo")`.

In this actual scenario I could do this by simply defining a getter for `obj.foo` like:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "foo", {
    get: () => obj.bar("foo")
});
```

But is it possible to do that for every method in advance (even ones that are not defined yet)? I mean without providing getters for every single method.

---

The best solution that I can see for now is iterating all the methods of `obj` after its full definition:

```
for (let methodName in obj)
    if (typeof obj[methodName] === "function" && methodName !== "bar")
        Object.defineProperty(obj, methodName, {
            get: () => obj.bar(methodName)
        });
```

Another one is starting every method with one repeated line of code – something unpleasant.

Are there solutions without iterating or self-repeating?

Comment: Here's a Proxy demo that I believe does what you're asking for: https://jsfiddle.net/gxhscwwb/

Comment: @squint: Thanks, it is helpful. Could you provide a similar answer for me to accept it?

Comment: I don't know enough about Proxies to give a decent answer. For example, I was a little surprised that we didn't end up with infinite recursion when accessing `target[name]` in the proxy handler, and I don't know exactly what the semantics allow. I'll let someone more knowledgeable about the topic post something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this in modern Javascript is with a Proxy object.

This is able (among other thing) to forward all the property accesses to an object to a handler.

So we can do something like this:

```
let origin = {
    bar(word) {
        console.log('bar: ', word);
    }
};

// wrap the origin object in a Proxy handler
let p = new Proxy(origin, {
    get(target, prop) {
        // wrap the value in a function
        return () => target.bar(prop);
    }
});

p.foo(); // outputs "bar: foo"
```

Note that this presumes you want to do `p.foo()`, rather than just `p.foo`. It wraps the value you want in a function. It will also forward the property access even if the property actually exists.

Comment: Will `p.bar()` will infinitely recurse? Or does the proxy prevent that?

Comment: Proxies are applied to already-instantiated objects though, right? They seem to be just slightly better than `.defineProperty()` in that you can cover all the properties on a given object at once.

Comment: @squint No, `target` is provided specifically to avoid that: it is the original wrapped object. The third (unused here) parameter to the `get` function is the proxified object.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Ouroborus You could have your constructor function return the proxy, rather than the original object.